# Select * where col1 is local max on each col2

Tags: mysql, sql, join, greatest-n-per-group

I have a few simliar tables. I need to select them through `*`.
I would like to get a list of the rows where `revnr` is the highest one within each `docid`.

My problem here is that I don't know how to get the local `max(revnr)` for each `docid`.

I am using MySQL but I'd prefer a general sql solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the latest value of `revnr` for each `docID` in a subquery then the result of that will then join to the table itself.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  docID, MAX(revnr) max_val
            FROM    tableName
            GROUP   BY docID
        ) b ON  a.docID = b.docID AND
                a.revnr = b.max_val
```

for better performance, add an `INDEX` on both columns: `docID` and `revnr`

```
ALTER TABLE tableName ADD INDEX (docID, revnr);
```

Comment: I've got a primary index on 3 cols, docid, revnr and one more.